# Issue with AWS Lambda Provisioned Concurrency using Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I have been trying to configure `Provisioned Concurrency` for my AWS Lambda function. I have been hitting `ValidationException` again and again. I tried `qualifier` attribute for both alias version and alias name. While `terraform apply` it waits for 2 mins and throws the error but it is configured successfully in AWS console with status ready. Below is my configuration.

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "contact_lambda_alias" {
  name             = module.aws_lambda_function_contact_alias_label.id
  function_name    = module.terraform_aws_lambda_contact.lambda_arn
  function_version = module.terraform_aws_lambda_contact.latest_published_version
}

resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "contact_lambda_alias" {
  function_name                     = module.terraform_aws_lambda_contact.lambda_arn
  provisioned_concurrent_executions = 1
  qualifier                         = module.terraform_aws_lambda_contact.latest_published_version
  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "30m"
  }
}
```

I tried with and without `timeouts` block but still hitting the `ValidationException` again and again .
This is the error
[ValidationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52wZs.png)

Comment: What **exactly** is the full error msg?

Comment: error getting Lambda Provisioned Concurrency Config (arn:aws:lambda:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:ifs-dev-customer-contact:4): ValidationException

Comment: Terraform state for `aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config` is messing with further apply. So I need to manually remove the resource from state and do an apply for other resources.

Comment: Moreover the API trigger for this alias lambda function where provisioned concurrency need to be configured is not configured.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **alias arn**:

```
 function_name = aws_lambda_alias.contact_lambda_alias.arn
```

Comment: According to docs in Terraform registry, `function_name` should be lambda arn and not that of alias.

Comment: This is the error `error putting Lambda Provisioned Concurrency Config (arn:aws:lambda:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:ifs-dev-customer-contact:ifs-dev-ax-contact-alias:4): InvalidParameterValueException: The derived qualifier from the function name does not match the specified qualifier.` when I tried with `function_name` with alias arn.

Comment: ```{
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "a3bc271b-5f82-4bfa-bac7-4c155996f6f0"
│   },
│   Message_: "The derived qualifier from the function name does not match the specified qualifier.",
│   Type: "User"
│ }```

Comment: @SreeTeja Prov Conc is only for alias or version as [AWS explains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html): "Provisioned Concurrency is not supported on $LATEST. " Even [TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config) use alias `function_name                     = aws_lambda_alias.example.function_name`

Comment: But `aws_lambda_alias.example.function_name` is `lambda_arn` itself, so I used lambda arn.

Comment: [Alias TF Docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_alias)

Answer (score 0):

Full working example as of 2023.

You need to use **depends_on.**

Do not use **arn** for **aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config.function_name** . See [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22392)

```
# Lambda
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  ...
  publish          = true // Need to publish because of aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config
  ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "my_lambda_alias" {
  depends_on       = [aws_lambda_function.my_lambda] // Important
  name             = "LATEST"
  description      = "Latest version"
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.my_lambdag.arn
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.lambda_wiseday_ml_rating.version
}

resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "my_lambda_concurrency_config" {
  depends_on                        = [aws_lambda_alias.my_lambda_alias] // Important
  function_name                     = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda.function_name // Not arn. Bug with arn.
  provisioned_concurrent_executions = 1
  qualifier                         = aws_lambda_alias.my_lambda_alias.name
}
```